# Text Alignment in ImageMagick (using RMagick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

Is there an easy way to do text alignment in Imagemagick generically?

I have some inherited Rails code which places some text on an image and aligns that text according to the configured alignment (left, center, right). The original code was:

```
alignment = custom_text.alignment.downcase
canvas = Magick::Draw.new
canvas.pointsize = font_size
canvas.fill = custom_text.color.to_s
canvas.font = custom_font.to_s

case alignment
  when "left"
    canvas.gravity = Magick::NorthWestGravity
  when "right"
    canvas.gravity = Magick::NorthEastGravity
  when "center"
    canvas.gravity = Magick::NorthGravity
  else
    canvas.gravity = Magick::NorthGravity
end

canvas.annotate(@base_image, width, height, x, y, content)
```

In this code you can probably guess what most of the variables are. A few notes for ones that may not be clear:

- @base_image - The image we are adding the text to
- `width`, `height`, `x`, `y` - Defines the box the text is placed in
- `content` - The actual text being added to the image

This seemed to work with "left" and "center" alignment. But sometimes for "right" alignment the text would not show (but not for all generated images).

Doing a bit of research I found [this page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/misc/convert/convert-draw-text.html) which seems to implying changing the gravity changes the coordinate system. This would explain why the text might disappear completely (although it seems it would be consistent).

I found the [`text_align`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#text_align) property that seemed more promising than gravity. It doesn't change the coordinate system although it does change how the text is placed relative to the starting point. So my attempt at fixing the problem is:

```
alignment = custom_text.alignment.downcase || 'center'
canvas = Magick::Draw.new
canvas.pointsize = font_size
canvas.fill = custom_text.color.to_s
canvas.font = custom_font.to_s
canvas.gravity = Magick::NorthWestGravity
offset = case alignment
  when "left"
    0
  when "right"
    width
  when "center"
    width / 2
end

canvas.annotate(@base_image, width, height, x + offset, y + font_size, content) do
  self.align = Magick.const_get "#{alignment.camelize}Align"
end
```

The offset added to the `x` is due to the fact that it changes the starting position. If left no offset if needed. If right then the width of the box is needed. If center then half of the box is needed.

If you look at [the screenshot in the documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#text_align) you will notice in addition to changing the starting point `x` it also move the starting point to the bottom of the text. Effectively making it off by one line. This is why I added the font size to `y`.

This initially seemed to work but the `y` aspect doesn't always work. Depending on the font being used it may or may not work.

Comment: Any progress with that issue?

Comment: check this, https://rmagick.github.io/text_align.rb.html